# Migrating Parallels to a new Machine

Tags: parallels-desktop

Hi I am migrating my Parallels install and VMs to a new machine. Is there an easy way to do this without having to reinstall all my software on my VM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is! The Unofficial Apple Weblog has dedicated [a whole topic about](http://www.tuaw.com/2007/06/29/moving-your-parallels-virtual-machine-to-another-mac/) moving your copies of Parallels.
Basically it's just a matter of copying your Parallels folder to the new Mac. The only thing you need to do, besides moving the folder, is reinstalling the Parallels Tools.

Comment: I've added some updated information with regards to Parallels 6 and 7 since the article you cited is from 2007.

Comment: Ok, great! But the basics stay the same, I see.

Answer (score 1):

With Parallels Desktop 6 and 7 this has been made even easier.

- Install Parallels Desktop on your new Mac
- Copy the complete PVM file to a folder on the new Mac
- Register and run Parallels and select `File` -> `Open`
- Select the moved PVM file
- At the Parallels prompt specify whether you copied or moved the file

The latter will generate new GUIDs for the file to ensure that it doesn't clash with any existing VM's on the new machine.

PS: Even easier option once Parallels is installed:

- Double click on the copied PVM file. This will launch Parallels and shortcut the above process.

Answer (score 0):

These answers didn't help for me.  I'm migrating Parallels 12, and Windows 10. I couldn't get my existing VM for Windows 10 to transfer to the new MacBook Pro.
Parallels Desktop is easily restored to the new Mac using Time Machine.  Note that the VM and Bootcamp are (ALWAYS) ignored by Time Machine, and must be transferred separately.
Get a USB stick, > 8GB, and format it using using http://www.disk-partition.com/diskpart/format-disk-partition-4125.html.
Insert USB stick in old machine so Windows 10 sees it.
In your old Windows 10 VM, download the "Media Creation Tool" here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/.
Create the Windows 10 image on the USB stick using mediacreationtool.
Eject USB stick from old Windows 10 machine.
Insert the USB stick into the Mac, and use Parallels Desktop: File/New to create the new VM.  Click "Install Windows from image file" and follow instructions.  It should auto locate the USB stick with the Windows 10 info.